# Google recaptcha v2 tick box isn't verifying

Tags: recaptcha

I've created a website through Dreamweaver with a simple contact form to fire off an email. Previously it didn't have recaptcha and worked fine, sending an email and showing success/failure messages correctly.
I've re-written it now using a Recaptcha v2 tick box, but now always get the error message "Invalid captcha", and no email.
The page presents correctly. 
The captcha presents correctly and allows you to make the selections then click the verify button, resulting in the green tick. However, when clicking the send button, it always fails.

Any help gratefully accepted.

Live website: https://www.simpleenglish.info/en/contact_us/contact_form.php

I confirm the site key and secret key are correct, as are all email addresses. I have deleted and created the keys and associated the domain through google admin twice, without success. I believe the code to be correct (no obvious errors). I haven't found any similar problem here or Google Groups to point me in a direction. I don't know where else to look.

The contact_form.php code (now complete):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/SE1.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Simple English Contact</title>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-136785269-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-136785269-1');
</script>

<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-1086244781484067",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
    </script>

    <link href="https://www.simpleenglish.info/SE_3ColLiquid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <style>
    .content { margin-right: -1px; } /* this 1px negative margin can be placed on any of the columns in this layout with the same corrective effect. */
    ul.nav a { zoom: 1; }  /* the zoom property gives IE the hasLayout trigger it needs to correct extra whiltespace between the links */
    </style>
<![endif]-->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="sidebar1"> <a href="https://www.simpleenglish.info/index.html"><img src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="Simple English Logo" width="99%"/></a>
    <ul class="nav" >      
      <li><a href="https://www.simpleenglish.info/index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.simpleenglish.info/en/vocabulary.html">Vocabulary</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.simpleenglish.info/en/usefullinks.html">Useful Links</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.simpleenglish.info/en/teachersaids.html">Teacher's Aids</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.simpleenglish.info/en/contact_us/contact_form.php">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.simpleenglish.info/en/sitemap.html">Site Map</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://www.simpleenglish.info/images/title.jpg" width="99%" alt="Simple English Title"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegionContent" -->
    <h1 class="pageheader">Contact Us</h1> 
    <p>To send us a message, please enter <strong>all the information</strong> in the following form, then click the 'Send' button.</p> 

      <div class="contact_us"> 
          <form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
              <table> 
                  <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="sendername" placeholder="Enter your full name" size="50" required="required"/></td></tr> 
                  <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="email" name="senderemail" placeholder="Enter your email address" size="50" required="required"/></td></tr> 
                  <tr><td>Message Context:</td><td><input type="text" name="sendercontext" placeholder="this will be context" size="50" required="required"/></td></tr> 
                  <tr><td>Message:</td><td><textarea name="sendermessage" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="How can we help you?" required="required"></textarea></td></tr> 
                  <tr><td>Spam Check:</td><td><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXX Correct Key XXX"></div></td></tr> 
                  <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit-btn"/></td></tr>
              </table> 
          </form> 

          <div class="status"> 
              <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
               { 
                $user_name = $_POST['sendername']; 
                $user_email = $_POST['senderemail']; 
                $user_context = $_POST['sendercontext']; 
                $user_message = $_POST['sendermessage']; 

                $email_from = 'contact@simpleenglish.info'; 
                $email_subject = "Simple English Contact"; 
                $email_body = "Name: $user_name.\n". 
                          "Email: $user_email.\n". 
                          "Context: $user_context.\n". 
                          "Message: $user_message.\n"; 
                $to_email = "admin@simpleenglish.com"; 
                $header = "From: $email_from \r\n"; 
                $header .= "Reply-To: $user_email \r\n"; 
                $secretkey = "XXX Correct Key XXX"; 
                $responsekey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']; 
                $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
                $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretkey&response=$responsekey&remoteip=$userip"; 

                $response = file_get_contents($url); 
                $response = json_decode($response); 

            if($response->success) 
            { 
                mail($to_email,$email_subject,$email_body,$header); 
                echo "Message sent successfully"; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                echo "Invalid Captcha. Please try again."; 
            } 
           } 
          ?> 
      </div> 
  </div>   

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!-- end .content --></div>

<div class="sidebar2">
<h4>&nbsp;</h4>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!-- end .sidebar2 --></div>

<div class="footer">
<p>Copyright © 2018<br />
   All rights reserved <!-- end .footer --></p>
</div>
<!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

Comment: Do a var_dump on `$response` and see what google is returning? Haven't used v2 in a while but the docs say the Method should be POST have you tried that?

Comment: Second2None, thanks for spotting that "POST". I've made the change, but no luck. I'll run a var_dump, but TBH don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you want to post the code you tried for POST? Also what did `$response` return?

Comment: I'm not sure how to post the code here, these comments have a char limit. If you can tell me how, I'll do it.
The result from the var_dump was "NULL" . Although by playing around, in one test I also got "bool(false)". As said previously, I don't know what these mean, but I hope that helps you ?

Comment: you can just edit your question and add it to the bottom. `file_get_contents` returns `false` on failure, do `var_dump($response)`  before you convert it to json, `json_decode` returns `NULL` on invalid json. I checked your form and `g-recaptcha-response` is being sent correctly. I'll post an answer below with how I normally check using file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

Your div tag for the recaptcha is not closed off properly. Do view page source and you'll see it in the table row.

```
<tr><td>Spam Check:</td><td><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc8OZ8UAAAAABUosvouUbamfotW9Pp-9ioRIEOZ"></td></tr>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't spot that error, but it didn't solve the problem. Same error as before.

Comment: So double checked your source code and all tags seems to be closed off properly. Only thing I can think of is your site key and secret key are not correct. p.s I took your code and used it on my site with my keys and works fine.

Comment: If you are really stuck, do you mind pasting the contents of the file you are working on?

Comment: Carlitos, 
many thanks for your help. I've double checked the code, run it through the Dreamweaver tools, and htmltidy.net and believe the code is correct (but accept I make mistakes and proofing my own code is always the hardest! :-)
I'm not sure how to paste the full file - comments has a character limit.

Answer (score 0):

Because I use classes I put this into a function. Google expects the method to be POST. You can do this with `file_get_contents` by setting `stream_context_create` options.

The rest is pretty self explanatory, `$secretkey` is your recaptcha secret key and `$captcha` is your `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

```
function checkRecaptcha( $secretkey , $captcha ){

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = [
        'secret' => $secretkey , 
        'response' => $captcha ,
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ,
    ];
    $options = [
        'http' => [
          'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
          'method'  => 'POST',
          'content' => http_build_query( $data )
          ]
    ];
    $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
    $contents = file_get_contents( $url , false , $context );
    $response = json_decode( $contents , true ); //convert to assoc array
    // if you want to use objects, remove true from json decode and then use $response->success
    if( ! $response["success"] ) { 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can then use it like:

```
<?php

function checkRecaptcha( $secretkey , $captcha ){

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = [
        'secret' => $secretkey , 
        'response' => $captcha ,
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ,
    ];
    $options = [
        'http' => [
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query( $data )
            ]
    ];
    $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
    $contents = file_get_contents( $url , false , $context );
    $response = json_decode( $contents , true ); //convert to assoc array
    // if you want to use objects, remove true from json decode and then use $response->success
    if( ! $response["success"] ) { 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if( isset($_POST['submit'] ) ) {

    $secretkey = "XXX Correct key here XXX";

    if( ! checkRecaptcha( $secretkey , $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {

        //only set variables if passes recaptcha

        //validate email address
        if ( ! filter_var( $_POST['senderemail'] , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo "Please provide a valid email";
            die();
        }

        //ensure user doesn't post HTML
        $user_name = strip_tags ( $_POST['sendername'] ); 
        $user_context = strip_tags ( $_POST['sendercontext'] );
        $user_message = strip_tags ( $_POST['sendermessage'] );

        $email_body = "Name: $user_name.\n"."Email: {$_POST['senderemail']}.\n"."Context: $user_context.\n"."Message: $user_message.\n";

        $header = "From: bla@simpleenglish.info \r\n";
        $header .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['senderemail']} \r\n";

        mail( 'bla@simpleenglish.com' , 'Simple English Contact' , $email_body , $header );
        echo "Message sent successfully";

    }else{

        echo "Invalid Captcha. Please try again.";

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks S2N, this is now giving the successful message and sending an email, but it will do so with or without the captcha - that is to say, I can submit a message and receive an email without doing the captcha. I know this because I am beginning to receive spam again :-(
As requested I have edited the original question to now include the original script complete.

Comment: Do an `isset` check on `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` to make sure it isn't blank.  Not sure why google is return success on an empty string